# Is multiple regression the correct approach?

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm having trouble deciding the correct approach to analyze a dataset. Say I have a big dataset of all the answers of a survey and I want to do profiles of the respondents that answered "NO" to a given question. To summarize, I'd study some variables of only the respondents that answered "NO" to that question; say gender, age, education years, etc...

I'm thinking I should do multiple regression to only the rows that match the condition. Or should I take the whole dataset for the regression? I get that multiple regression studies the variability of the individuals on a set of characteristics but I can't decide on it.

Also, this is not homework, so I've marked it as self-study because I have my exam next week. Any resource you could also point me to would be perfect!

Comment: Please can you carefully explain what your research question/s is/are ? This will inform the choices of modelling. If you are only interested in profiles of responsers then maybe some sort of clustering or factor analysis would be appropriate but without more details it is very difficult to advise.

Comment: I am with Robert Long that as long as this question lacks details. Something similar to regression analysis that may be worth looking into is linear discriminant analysis (LDA) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis . On other thing to try to find characteristics of "No"-profiles may bei a classification tree (CART etc.).

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in a logistic regression, and then can simply interpret the coefficients

Comment: @RobertLong sorry for the chaotic question! So, imagine a survey made on a handful of respondents; one question can be answered to a YES (1 on the dataset) or NO (2 on the dataset) and DK/NA/REF (3 on the dataset). I want to analyze the profiles of the people who answered NO, based on some other variables that they answered on the survey, which are going to be quantitative.